# how to add scroll to my WinJS app VS2012

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro app (WinJS) in VS2012 which loads an image  inside a  by using an  a from my local disk like which next function

```
function loadPictureFromFile(event) {

    var selectedFile    = event.target.files[0];
    var reader          = new FileReader();

    imageElement = document.createElement("img");               //creates <img id="img"> element
    imageElement.title = selectedFile.name;                     //set photo's name

    reader.onload = function (event) {
        imageElement.setAttribute("src", event.target.result);  //picture's source
        _divPicture.appendChild(imageElement);                  //Add's <img> element to Div element
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
}
```

but sometimes my image is too big to display on screen, it requires a scroll for viewing it completely, how to add it from javascript or WinJS after loading picture??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your default.css simply add

```
body {
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```